# Visual Studio 2019 not updating/removing a service reference

Tags: visual-studio, service-reference

Visual Studio 2019 is not updating a mex service reference. If I try to remove the service reference, the problem gets worse, and the service reference gets marked with a red cross and it is not possible to go back to the previous state.

The error message includes the error code 0x8007007c.

Restarting the IDE does not solve anything.

Answer (score 1):

A system process misteriously blocked a file inside the service references folder, and Visual Studio doesn't make it clear with its messages.

Restarting the IDE wasn't a solution because the process was independent from the IDE. Rebooting the system (or finding a way to kill the process with the file handle) is the solution. Probably a Visual Studio bug.

Since it took me two hours and there wasn't any post citing this error code 0x8007007c and the correct solution, I came here to post the problem/solution I would like to have read before.